# Use value from STRING_SPLIT function inside CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, contains

I am trying to create SQL query (via full-text search) which will return along with CONTAINS multiple terms over multiple columns.

Below what I managed to create:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Sample text to be splitted', ' ')
WHERE CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), value))
```

I have no idea why I can't use 'value' inside contains due to syntax error: "Incorrect syntax near 'value'". I am using SQL Server, I have full-text index, only problem is with 'value' column from splitted string, I can use explicit string (e.g 'text') in place of 'value' and then it works but that's not the solution.

Comment: The value of the `contains_search_condition` needs to be a literal or variable; it can't be a column.

Comment: You may try to use a JOIN and LIKE to solve this isuue.

Comment: How can I extract value from the column? Cause in fact under 'value' there's a text value.

Comment: @Zhorov I know it's possible with LIKE however it requires separate 3 conditions to be written. With contains it would look more readable.

Comment: Maybe there's another way to extract all values from STRING_SPLIT function and then pass it to CONTAINS one by one?

Comment: `CONTAINS` accepts a parameter for `@SearchWord` so you can put this into an inline TVF and pass the string split value in as a parameter to that

Comment: Could use a TVF like this https://dbfiddle.uk/a1wwuqeh

Comment: The choice between `LIKE` and `CONTAINS` shouldn't be based on what looks nicest though (fewest conditions)  as they don't do the same thing or are implemented at all the same.

Comment: @MartinSmith So `LIKE` would be better for this case? Primarily I wanted to use `CONTAINS` like that `CONTAINS((col1, col2, col3), CONCAT('"*sample*"', ' AND ', '"*text*"'...))` However SQL Server in such case checks if all the words in CONCAT are present together in any column and I would like to check if these words appear in these columns but not every word in one column. E.g 'sample' present in col1 and 'text' in col3 would meet the condition but that's not how it works as e.g. col1 must contain both of these words

Comment: Full text search is about matching words. `LIKE` is about matching exact substrings. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Full-text doesn't really do full wildcard search (with leading wildcard) you are going to want `LIKE` for that

Comment: That was my misunderstanding as I have seen in docs that wildcards could be used inside contains. So finally such solution `SELECT * FROM table AS t WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('sample text to be splitted', ' ') AS S WHERE t.col1 NOT LIKE CONCAT('%', s.value, '%') AND t.col2...)` is ok to return records that have given words present in such columns together?

Comment: I encountered a problem implementing TVF as you suggested above, error 'The inline function SearchTable cannot take correlated parameters or subqueries because it uses a full-text operator'

Comment: I think I misunderstand something, I would appreciate if someone could explain it to me. I can use in `contains_search_condition` variable declared as varchar but I can not use value from SPLIT_STRING function which returns exactly a substring - so anyway it is a string. It is not possible to create literal/variable from the value column?

Comment: It's even more weird to me as I can use `WHERE col1 = s.value` and it works completely fine so SQL knows the value of 'value'

Comment: It looks like I can not pass s.value as parameter to function due to 'The inline function SearchTable cannot take correlated parameters or subqueries because it uses a full-text operator' error. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

A manually prepared select statement from your multi-word string would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), 'Sample') OR
      CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), 'text') OR
      CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), 'to') OR
      CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), 'be') OR
      CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), 'split');
```

So you can see that is your input string is 12 words, or 123 words, that the structute of the query would alter a lot. So you need a way to deal with this variablity - and this requires "dynamic sql" i.e. a script to build the needed sql, then to execute that sql. To prepare such a variable select statement requires iterating through the split values as in this example which places the split words into a table, then concatenates the sql together for each row in that table:

```
DECLARE @SearchText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Sample text to be split';
DECLARE @SplitValues TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(100)); -- Adjust the length as needed

INSERT INTO @SplitValues
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@SearchText, ' ');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM table WHERE';

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Value FROM @SplitValues
)
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + '  CONTAINS((column1, column2, column3), ''' + Value + ''') OR'
FROM CTE;

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 2); -- this removes the trailing 'OR'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

**nb** this script may create queries that are inefficient and slow to run

Comment: suggested reading [Splitted or Split: The Past Form of “Split”](https://www.tprteaching.com/splitted-or-split/)